# Difficulty in using slot to declare math symbol

Tags: declare

I am trying to use declare math symbol using `\DeclareMathSymbol` command but I am unable to understand how to use slot for the symbol of integers. Following is the snippet of my code:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Z}{\mathop}{CMlargesymbols}{"55}
```

The slot in the `\DeclareMathSymbol` is wrong. I found out the following list but don't know how to extract slot from it. I would be really thankful if someone could help me with this as I have literally spent hours on it.

[image]

Comment: why not `\mathbb{Z}` from amsfonts? cmex does not have a Z, also you would normally want this to be a mathord not mathop

Comment: Because I am using mathpazo as the font for all other symbols.

Comment: but you are loading cmex not a mathpazo font the chart you post shows Z in normal ASCII slot for Z hex 5A but it is not the chart of the cmex font you are using

Comment: generally newpxmath Is recommended over the old psnfss packages it includes a matching blackboard bold font

Comment: The font table you show isn't `cmex`.

Answer (score 2):

According to comments on the question, you seem to want to replace `mathpazo` blackboard bold letters with the usual `amsfonts` ones.

The method is simple: look in `amsfonts` to see

```
\@ifundefined{mathbb}{%
    \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}%
}{}
```

Since `mathpazo` does define `\mathbb`, loading `amsfonts` will not override it. But you can! Look for `AMSb` to find

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
```

OK, now we just need to define a math alphabet from the data available. Remember to use the `noBBpl` option, so `\mathbb` is not defined by `mathpazo`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc,noBBpl]{mathpazo}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

This is palatino text $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

\end{document}
```

[image]